# Question related to the word Either

Tags: grammar, pronouns, writing, learning, either-or

In the following sentences does the word 'either' means 'both' or 'any one'

1. Either of these roads leads to the railway station.
2. Either of you can go.

Comment: In the first sentence it means both, while the second one is a bit more ambiguous and needs context.  If it is said by a parent to their children about going to a concert, it can mean birth.  If it is said by a gunman to his hostages on another hand....

Comment: I think in all statements where the syntactic subject is ***either** [**of** some contextually relevant pair]*, the implication is *only **one** of the pair will be "chosen" (but it doesn't matter **which one**)*. So replacing ***either*** with ***both*** does NOT mean the same thing, since that implies ***both possibilities may be selected at the same time*** (just look how often the sequence [***either but not both***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22either+but+not+both%22)) occurs in print).

Comment: Yes. Either can mean *both* or *any one*. If it's not clear from context, it needs to be made explicit.